# Why angular/cli 1.5.4 download angular version is 5.0.0 rather than 5.0.3

Tags: angular, version, angular-cli

`ng new project`

**Why angular-cli 1.5.4 download angular version is 5.0.0 rather than 5.0.3? The angular.io said that the stable version is 5.0.3**

Comment: Try `npm update` in your project folder

Comment: Please check answer in you case its ^ or ~ in package.json it will take 5.0.3 but not show same thing in Package.json , in package.josn its like ~5.0.0 or ^5.0.0

Comment: Which versions are shown by `ng version` before you try to run `ng new project`

Answer (score 1):

check your `package.json` file, if there is `~` in front of angular version or `^`.

```
~ means - 
In the simplest terms, the tilde matches the most recent minor version
(the middle number). ~1.2.3 will match all 1.2.x versions but will miss

^ means -The caret, on the other hand, is more relaxed. It will update you 
 to the most recent major version (the first number). ^1.2.3 will 
match any 1.x.x release including 1.3.0, but will hold off on 2.0.0.
```

Read this : http://fredkschott.com/post/2014/02/npm-no-longer-defaults-to-tildes/

Comment: the package.json is  ^ .

Comment: @rain - -The caret, on the other hand, is more relaxed. It will update you 
 to the most recent major version (the first number). ^1.2.3 will 
match any 1.x.x release including 1.3.0, but will hold off on 2.0.0

Comment: @rain - check my answer i updatd for that also ...it will take 5.0.3

Comment: @rain - please go through http://fredkschott.com/post/2014/02/npm-no-longer-defaults-to-tildes/

Comment: thank u. I very suprised why you answer my question so fast?

Comment: @rain - because i went through package.json file once and in one seminar i got to know meaning of ^ ot ~ ...please accept and upvote answer if it helped you

Comment: @rain - ..please accept and upvote answer if it helped you